# Cassandra Asyn connection limit

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I get the data from one table and then I iterate on that ResultSet to fetch data from another table ( executeAsync() ). I want to control the number of async tasks.

```
for(Row row : resultSites) {
        String siteName = row.getString("site_name");
        System.out.println(siteName);
        ResultSetFuture future = casCon.session.executeAsync(casCon.boundStatement.bind(siteName));
        Futures.addCallback(future,fCR,MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executorService));
    }
```

My Executor and FutureCallback are

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    FutureCallback<ResultSet> fCR = new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
                @Override public void onSuccess(ResultSet result) {
                    System.out.println(result.one());
                }
                @Override public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("Error while reading Cassandra version: " + t.getMessage());
            }
        };
```

Now by searching I found this and implemented it in my code

```
PoolingOptions poolingOpts = new PoolingOptions();
            poolingOpts.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2);
               poolingOpts.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 4);
               poolingOpts.setMaxSimultaneousRequestsPerConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.REMOTE, 10);
               poolingOpts.setMinSimultaneousRequestsPerConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2);
               poolingOpts.setMinSimultaneousRequestsPerConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, 2);
               poolingOpts.setMaxSimultaneousRequestsPerConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, 10);


            cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(ip)
                    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy())
                    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOpts)
                    .withCredentials(user, pass)
                    .withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
```

But when I call

```
System.out.println(session.getCluster().getConfiguration().getPoolingOptions().getMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE));
```

I get null pointer exception so I am not sure if I have implemented it properly ? Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: Please post the exception and stack trace

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at CassandraCon.connect(CassandraCon.java:41) at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:57) : Line 41 of CassandraCon is System.out.println(session.getCluster().getConfiguration().getPoolingOptions(‌​).getMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE));

Comment: It's difficult to know where the NPE could be coming from without seeing more code.  Is it possible session is null?   Have you tried putting a breakpoint at your 'System.out.println' call to see the state of the session at the time.

In addition, the driver will throw an exception if you exceed the number of concurrent requests.  What are you using as the basis for controlling the maximum simultaneous requests?  I'd recommend reading this article for pointers: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries

Comment: Thanks . This might be the most stupidest mistake I ever made. Without debugging I made this assumption I am not reading the API right. :(  Session was not connected to the cluster. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Ahh, that would do it, good catch :)